# Tokenizing words in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk

I am having a problem with tokenizing words in panda series.

my series named `df`:

```
                        text
0     This monitor is a great deal for the price.
1     I would recommend it.
2     poor packaging.
dtype: object
```

I had tried `df_tokenized=nltk.word_tokenize(df)` but result in `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

I also tried 3 variations of `.apply(lambda row:)`

```
df_tokenized=df.apply(lambda row: nltk.word_tokenize(row['text']), axis=1)
> TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

df_tokenized=df.apply(lambda row: nltk.word_tokenize(row['text']))
> TypeError: string indices must be integers

df_tokenized=df.apply(lambda row: nltk.word_tokenize(row[1]))
> TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Are there any other ways to tokenize words from series?

Comment: if you found the answer useful, could you please mark the question as answered (gray tick symbol on the left of the answer) and upvote it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use any of the below (which is the first one you cited):

```
import nltk
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'text': [' This monitor is a great deal for the price.',
                            'I would recommend it.',
                            'poor packaging.']})
print(df.info())

df_tokenized = df.apply(lambda row: nltk.word_tokenize(row['text']), axis=1)

print(df_tokenized)
```

And the output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   text    3 non-null      object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 152.0+ bytes

     

                                  text
0   This monitor is a great deal for the price.
1                         I would recommend it.
2                               poor packaging.
0    [This, monitor, is, a, great, deal, for, the, ...
1                         [I, would, recommend, it, .]
2                                 [poor, packaging, .]
dtype: object
```

Comment: @Win Wongsawatdichart: could you please approve the answer if helpful (the gray tick  mark on the left from the answer)?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, my data is in a series type and I know now that there is no axis selection in `series.apply()`. But the next problem I occur is   `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` I try using .str but it does not really seem to work. do you have advice? nonetheless, thank you so much for the replies, really appreciated.

Comment: oh, I figure it out, turns out my series have NA values so it can not use the function.

Comment: You can add an if clause to the function applied using `df.apply` to use it only on non-NA values.